# Oracle SQL query for Group By with Having clause

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have Table A below:

```
HashKey     QueueStatus     CreationDateTime
1             IMM           21-NOV-18 01.56.28.977628000 AM
1             DEF           21-NOV-18 01.58.28.971628000 AM
1             SENT          21-NOV-18 01.59.28.977628000 AM
2             IMM           21-NOV-18 02.56.28.977628000 AM
2             MAN           21-NOV-18 02.57.28.977628000 AM
2             SENT          21-NOV-18 02.58.28.977628000 AM
```

I have another table B below:

```
HashKey     ReleaseStatus  TrxNo  
1             SENT          XYZ
2             SENT          XYZ
3             null           XYZ
```

Now I need a query which gives me The all columns from B table which have the ReleaseStatus as SENT and previous Queue status(CreationDateTime is the factor to decide) from Table A.

In this example I need the result as -

```
HashKey     ReleaseStatus  TrxNo   QueueStatus as PrevoiusQueueStatus
  1           SENT           XYZ       DEF
  2           SENT           XYZ       MAN
```

I have tried with having & group by queries on Table A but not able to getting the previous one by Having clause.

Some of trial (select Hashkey,count(creationdatetime) from QueuedRecords group by Hashkey having creationdatetime

Comment: Is your final timestamp in table A supposed to be 02:58, rather than 01:58?

Comment: Thats right Alex.edited

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than grouping, you can use the `lag()` analytic function to get the previous status for each row in table A:

```
select HashKey,
  QueueStatus,
  lag(QueueStatus) over (partition by HashKey order by CreationDateTime) as PreviousQueueStatus
from tablea
```

and then use that as a subquery (CTE or inline view) and join it to table B:

```
select b.HashKey, b.ReleaseStatus, b.TrxNo, a.PreviousQueueStatus
from tableb b
join (
  select HashKey,
    QueueStatus,
    lag(QueueStatus) over (partition by HashKey order by CreationDateTime) as PreviousQueueStatus
  from tablea
) a
on a.HashKey = b.HashKey
and a.QueueStatus = b.ReleaseStatus
where b.ReleaseStatus = 'SENT';

   HASHKEY RELE TRX PREV
---------- ---- --- ----
         1 SENT XYZ DEF 
         2 SENT XYZ MAN
```

To get that result I've assumed that the time in your final 2/SENT row in table A is supposed to be the last time for that HashKey, e.g. 02:58 rather than 01:58, since that's supposed to be controlling which other value you see.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c26dac862303a542f9834efe90a11170)

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH prev as 
(SELECT HASHKEY, QUEUESTATUS, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HASHKEY ORDER BY CREATEDATETIME DESC) rn 
FROM tA) 
select tB.*, prev.QUEUESTATUS 
FROM tB JOIN prev ON tB.HASHKEY = prev.HASHKEY
where tB.RELEASESTATUS='SENT' and prev.rn = 2;
```